# Append results of a filter to the end of another filter in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

How can I append the results of one filter function to the end of the result of another filter function with one row in between using a formula (not apps script)?

I tried this: ={(FILTER(A2:C,COUNTIF(E2:E&F2:F,A2:A&B2:B))),(FILTER(A2:C,COUNTIF(E2:E&F2:F,A2:A&B2:B)))}, but it merges by column, not by row.

Answer (score 1):

*You may try:*

```js
=ifna(vstack(
        FILTER(A2:C,COUNTIF(E2:E&F2:F,A2:A&B2:B),A2:A<>"")
        ,, 
        FILTER(A2:C,COUNTIF(E2:E&F2:F,A2:A&B2:B),A2:A<>"")
        ))
```